# お礼に関係するバッジの名称が実際の名称と異なる

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

### 不具合事象

「[お礼の設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)」権限に関連するバッジとして、以下の四つが挙げられています。しかし、実際にはこれらの名称のバッジには別名称が付けられています。

Before:

> #### お礼に関係するのはどのバッジですか?
>
> - プロモーター — 自分の質問にお礼を開始
> - 投資家 — 他の人の質問にお礼を開始
> - 利他主義者 — 他の人の質問に手動でお礼を授与
> - 後援者 — 自分の質問にお礼を手動で授与

---

### 修正案

このため、文章を以下のように修正する必要があると思います。蛇足ですが、以下の修正案ではバッジの説明文を[バッジ一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)の説明に合わせました。

After:

> #### お礼に関係するのはどのバッジですか?
>
> - 自費広告 — 自分自身の質問に初めてお礼を提示した
> - スポンサー — 別のユーザーの質問に初めてお礼を授与した
> - 篤志家 — 別のユーザーの質問に初めて手動でお礼を授与した
> - パトロン — 自分自身の質問に初めて手動でお礼を授与した

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nicolas さんにお願いし、文章を直してもらいました。現在は修正案の文章になっています :)

[image]