# ヘルプセンター:「お礼の設定」の改善

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

この投稿は「[お礼の設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)」の改善案です ([英語の原文はこちら](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties))。コミュニティの総意を反映し「お礼」を「懸賞」に書き換えたいと思います！その他にも改善できる箇所があれば編集やコメントをお願いします。

---

### 懸賞の設定

#### 懸賞とは？

懸賞とは、ちょうど 1 週間、質問により多くの注意を喚起するために、質問につけることができる信用度の賞です。

#### どんな時に懸賞を設定したらいいですか？

よい回答を得るためには、質問に努力を注がなければなりません。質問を編集してステータスと進捗の最新情報を提示します。質問に回答するために自分が続けている努力について説明します。これにより、質問が自然に上昇し、より多くの人が興味を持ってくれます。

しかし、そうした後で特定の質問が*まだ*十分に注目されていないと感じる場合は、懸賞を追加すると役立つ場合があります。

#### 懸賞の設定方法は？

懸賞を設定するには、 [**懸賞を提示する**] ボタンをクリックします。このボタンは質問のコメント エリアの*下*にあります。

[image: 「懸賞を開始する」インターフェース]

ドロップダウン メニューを使用して、授与する信用度の量を調整してから、 [**懸賞を開始**] をクリックします。

#### 懸賞を設定するとどうなりますか？

- 質問は直ちにアクティブな質問のリストのトップに上昇します。
- 質問は 7 日間、ホーム ページの [[**懸賞付き**] タブ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured)におかれます。
- 懸賞に使用する信用度は、ただちに信用度から控除され元には戻せません。
- 信用度の変化により権限の要件を満たさなくなった場合、そのような権限にアクセスできなくなります。

7 日間の懸賞期間またはその後の猶予期間中に懸賞を授与するのはあなたの責任です。懸賞期間が終了に近づくと、電子メールとサイト通知を何通か受け取ります。

#### どの質問に懸賞を設定できますか？

質問に懸賞ボタンが表示されない場合は、以下の項目が該当します。

- その質問は過去 **48** 時間以内に質問された場合。まず、コミュニティが通常の方法で質問に回答する機会を与えます。
- 未処理の懸賞がすでに 3 個ある場合。同時にオープンできる懸賞は 3 個までです。この質問に懸賞を開始するには、まず以前の懸賞のすくなくとも 1 つを授与しなければなりません。
- 質問にすでに懸賞がある場合。この質問に 2 番目の懸賞を開始するには、まず現在の懸賞が授与されるのを待たなければなりません。

懸賞を提供するのに、質問者である必要はありません。

#### 懸賞授与の方法は？

懸賞は、賛成投票/反対投票インターフェースの下の該当するボタンをクリックすると授与できます。以下の点に注意してください。

- [コミュニティ Wiki の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)は懸賞の対象になります。
- 懸賞を授与せずに回答を承認できます。
- 回答を承認せずに懸賞を授与できます。
- 懸賞を授与するには、24 時間待たなければなりません。
- 懸賞の授与は元に戻せません。

#### 懸賞はいつ期限切れになりますか？

懸賞は 7 日後に期限切れになります。その数日前にいくつかの通知を受け取ります。
懸賞期間の終了後 24 時間以内に懸賞を授与しないと、懸賞の開始後に投稿された回答で最も高い投票のものに懸賞の額の*半分*が授与されます。ただし、最低でも 2 点のスコアがなければなりません。この要件に該当する新しい回答がない場合、信用度はまったく授与されず、懸賞に使用された信用度は永遠に失われます。

懸賞をいったん開始すると、信用度はいかなる状況でも払い戻しできないことに注意してください。

#### 懸賞に関係するのはどのバッジですか？

- 自費広告 — 自分自身の質問に初めて懸賞を提示した
- スポンサー — 別のユーザーの質問に初めて懸賞を授与した
- 篤志家 — 別のユーザーの質問に初めて手動で懸賞を授与した
- パトロン — 自分自身の質問に初めて手動で懸賞を授与した

---

関連：

- [日本語に違和感：「お礼」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/163/14055)
- [日本語に違和感: 「おすすめ」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2650/14055)
- [お礼に関係するバッジの名称が実際の名称と異なる](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3193/14055)

Comment: 他の関連投稿もですが、HTML と Markdown が入り混じっているのはなぜでしょうか？ Markdown が問題無く使用できるのであれば統一したいです。

Comment: これまでにこのような改善ドラフトでHTMLからMarkdown に変更くださりそのまま適用されたヘルプページも存在しますのでMarkdownに統一する方向で良いと思われます。確かな数字は不明ですがおそらく15件ほどのヘルプページは（或いはもっとたくさんあるのかもしれませんが）現在HTMLで書かれているようです。

Comment: @supa さん、スクリーンショットの更新助かりました。[合計 $OpenBountiesPerUser$のストリング](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/6166)の反映が今日これから行われるようです。大変おそれいりますが反映後にもう一度アップデートをお願いしなくてなりませぬ m_ _m

Comment: スクリーンショットのアップデート感謝です！週末、CMのニックさんに変更依頼済みですので、反映まであと少しかと。時差がありまして申し訳ありません m_ _m